# How to pass information to and from RequestHandler in socket server

Tags: python, sockets, networking, python-3.x

I have a class that manages a socketserver. Information needs to be passed in both directions between it and the handler. There are some work arounds I can use to get the Handler to pass information to the game server, but not the other way around. It seems like a pretty common need. It's also possible that there's a better way to do this whole thing and that I'm violating some common practice, in which case I'd like to know so I can write my code in a more standard way (I'm not trying to do anything fancy).

```
class GameServer:
    class GameServerUDPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
        #... (other, irrelevant functions)
        def handle(self):
            data = self.request[0].strip()
            data = str(data, 'utf-8')
            print(data)
            socket = self.request[1]
            data = data.split('\n')
            option = data[0]
            print(option)
            c_add = self.client_address
            if option == "register" and not self.server.base.has_started:
                self.handle_register(socket, c_add)
                print("test")
            elif option == "get_postion":
                handle_get_postion(socket, c_add, data[1])
            elif option == "change_postion":
                hande_changed_postion(socket, c_add, data[1])
            #temporary
            if len(self.server.base.players) > 0:
                self.server.base.start

    def __init__(self, port):
        self.server = socketserver.UDPServer(("localhost", port), self.GameServerUDPHandler)

    def start_server(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.server.serve_forever).start()

    def start_game():
        self.has_started = True
        self.server.RequestHandler.alert_start()
```

Comment: what is 'information', why not use a callback?